# Get value between two substrings using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

If I have a string "Param1=value1;Param2=value2;Param3=val3", how can I get the value between the substrings "Param2=" and the next semicolon (or end of string, whichever comes first)?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Param\d+=([^;]*)" will capture the contents between = and ; in group 1

Answer (score 3):

`/Param2=([^;]+)/`

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a character class that excludes `;` (as others have answered), or you can use a non-greedy match anything:

```
/Param2=(.*?);/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this string to place all of the values into the Matches collection of the [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex_members.aspx) class

```
string regex = "Param[0-9]*?=(?<value>.*?)(;|$)"
```